# Why is this code returning a line break before the echo?

Tags: php, line-breaks

So I have this login php script that I am using and it works fine on one server (returns "success" || "invalid login") and then this other server it breaks because it returns a line break and then "success" or "invalid login"

My guess is a php.ini setting. I am just not sure which one.

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
include("../connect.php");

$adminCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' AND password = '" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "'");
if (mysql_num_rows($adminCheck) == 1)
{
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($adminCheck);
    $_SESSION['user']['level']    = "admin";
    $_SESSION['user']['userid']   = $result['id'];
    $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $result['username'];
    echo "success"; 
}
else
{
    $clientCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' AND password = '" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($clientCheck) == 1)
    {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($clientCheck);
        $_SESSION['user']['level']      = "client";
        $_SESSION['user']['userid']     = $result['id'];
        $_SESSION['user']['username']   = $result['username'];
        $_SESSION['user']['client']     = $result['client'];
        echo "success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "invalid login";   
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Check inside `config.php` and `connect.php`, could be happening in there

Comment: oh right..duh..be back in a sec

Comment: sorry..waiting for the client to email me the files...

Comment: alright I am looking at config and connect.php. Everything looks fine. Only thing I noticed was after the closing PHP tag, there were a couple of extra lines so I removed them and I'm having the client reupload the files. If that doesn't solve it, I will post the code to those two files

Comment: Looks like that was the issue. A couple of blank lines at the end of config.php It's all good now.

Comment: PHP's `ext/mysql` (the `mysql_*` family) is [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).  Please use [something else](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet you a coke that connect.php or config.php contain a \n (or \r\n) before or after their `<?php ?>` parts.

Comment: this was indeed the reason. Instead of a coke, I'll give you a few points as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely due to your includes. The code you posted has no reason to have one, and there is no php.ini setting that I'm aware of to add such.

Post your config and connect (with username/pw hidden) for us to help further.

Comment: it looks like he needs connect.php, otherwise his mysql_query function calls would fail...

Comment: I was referring to 'no reason' his posted code wouldn't work. Not that he didn't need the includes ;)

Comment: ahh that makes a lot more sense :)

Answer (score 1):

The code displayed does not indicate the occurrence of a line-break.

On a side note since you are only outputting one value from your booleans then you could initialize a variable to hold the response and then only echo the response once:

```
<?php
include("../config.php");
include("../connect.php");

$response = 'success';

$adminCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM admins WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' AND password = '" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "'");
if (mysql_num_rows($adminCheck) == 1)
{
    $result = mysql_fetch_array($adminCheck);
    $_SESSION['user']['level']    = "admin";
    $_SESSION['user']['userid']   = $result['id'];
    $_SESSION['user']['username'] = $result['username'];
}
else
{
    $clientCheck = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients WHERE username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "' AND password = '" .  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($clientCheck) == 1)
    {
        $result = mysql_fetch_array($clientCheck);
        $_SESSION['user']['level']      = "client";
        $_SESSION['user']['userid']     = $result['id'];
        $_SESSION['user']['username']   = $result['username'];
        $_SESSION['user']['client']     = $result['client'];
    }
    else
    {
        $response = "invalid login";   
    }
}

echo $response;
?>
```